# Can we simply get the edges of the graphs when using networkx GraphMatcher?

Tags: networkx, matching, edges, isomorphism

We use Python networkx GraphMatcher to find matchings of two graphs G1 and G2:

```
from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism

GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1, G2)
matchings_list = list(GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter())
```

For example, matchings_list is [{'4':'0', '11': '1', '8': '2', '7': '3'}, {'4': '0', '11': '1', '15': '2', '6': '3'}].

Each matching in the matchings_list is a dictionary whose **keys are vertices of G1**, and **values are vertices of G2**.

If we want to get vertices of G1, we can easily access like matching.keys().

But, **how can we simply access the edges of G1**?

The long way to access them is to traverse the edges of G2 with G2.edges, and get the corresponding G1 vertices from the matching (create a reverse dictionary of the matching since keys are G1' vertices), and create a tuple for making an edge.

Comment: Can't you just use `G1.subgraph(matching.keys()).edges`?

Comment: It is slower than the long way. @Timus

Comment: Okay, that's not what I expected. Good to know.